# React Native OneSignal 3.9.3 not receiving push notifications

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I recently updated my React Native app to compile to Android 12.

in **build.gradle**

```
targetSdkVersion = 31
compileSdkVersion = 31
```

I have managed to create a workaround for making React Native OneSignal 3.9.3 compatible with Android 12, and in-app notifications is working as expected.

However, I do not receive any **push notifications**.

Here is the code I added in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver
    android:exported="false"
    android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
    tools:replace="android:exported">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.myapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>       

<receiver
    android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedReceiver"
    android:exported="false"
    tools:replace="android:exported">
</receiver>

<receiver
    android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:replace="android:exported">
</receiver>

<receiver
    android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    tools:replace="android:exported">
</receiver>
```

Did I miss anything? I can't upgrade to OneSignal 4.x at the moment since there are breaking changes.